# Clojure - splitting time string to find distinct hours

Tags: clojure, split

I am working with a data set that has a time column formatted like so:

```
    {:time "00:00:00"}
    {:time "03:05:12"}
    {:time "09:45:14"}
    {:time "13:01:22"}
    {:time "19:29:31"}
```

I have run a SQL query to find these times although I need to be able to find the distinct hour only, potentially by splitting the string. I have tried:

```
    t(get (split (:time data)  #":") 0)
```

But it returns all of the data in the db except what I want - I am trying to split the time after the first : and only keep the first element of the split distinctly.

Ideally I just want the hours returned such as '00' '03' '09' '13' '19' but I am unsure how to do this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless there's any reason why the hours would be ever anything else than the first two characters, you could just do

```
(subs (:time data) 0 2)
```

If you really need all the characters before the first `:` and that's not always in the same position,  you can still use `subs`, but combined with `.indexOf`:

```
(let [s (:time data)]
  (subs s 0 (.indexOf s ":")))
```